# Google Website Translator completely changes site spacing and structure

Tags: html, css, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I embedded Google Website Translator into the website I'm working on when Google Analytics showed me that the majority of website traffic is coming from non-English speaking locations.

The translation works, and I'm happy that the site will be available to more people.  The problem is that, when translated, the structure and formatting of my pages are thrown entirely out the window.  For the most part, font colors and sizes are maintained, but tables change width and most line breaks are ignored...this leaves a jumbled mess with very little structure.  It can still be read, it just gets even uglier than it already was.

To see for yourself, visit the website at [SVFCLV.org](http://www.SVFCLV.org) and translate into any language you'd like.  What's the easiest way to preserve my page structure even when Google translates the page for visitors?